# C++ Style Comments for Microsoft Word 2008?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2008

I would like to be able use some sort of C++ style commenting for Microsoft Word.

E.g. If I have

// line of text

the entire line should be a comment and should appear in a different colour.

Same goes for:

/*

text block

*/

I would want text block to be in a different colour than my main text.

Another feature that would be nice but not necessary for me to have is some sort of a way to quickly strip all the comments.

I have no idea how this could be done, if possible.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: related Stack Overflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070614/syntax-highlight-with-word-2007

Comment: This could be possible by setting up a comment style (which only goes until the end of the line in case of // comments); and then make // and /* resp. react on auto-format which in turn triggers the style.

Comment: Can you 'prove' that with a screenshot/example? Else I'm sure it would get accepted as an answer

Answer (score 0):

If your comments are delimited `/*` and `*/` then stripping them and delimiters all in one go is possible with Search for `(/\*)*(\*/)` and Replace with nothing. `/{2}*^l` should locate an entire line beginning `//` and ending with a line break (may look like a one but is an el).

Having located text in this way it can be "deleted and then reinserted" with changed formatting (eg font colour) by replacement with `^&` in the Replace box formatted to suit.

Note that the above searches and replacements would require Use wildcards being ticked.